# Outlook email script read UTF8 file

Tags: email, vbscript, outlook, signature

```
On Error Resume Next
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strUser = objSysInfo.UserName
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strUser)
strName = objUser.FullName
strTitle = objUser.Description
strCred = objUser.Info
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add()
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
strFailas1 = "1.jpg"
strFailas2 = "2.jpg"
strFailas3 = "3.jpg"
strFailas4 = "4.jpg"
strSPath1 = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%") & "\Appdata\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\" & strFailas1
strSPath2 = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%") & "\Appdata\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\" & strFailas2
strSPath3 = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%") & "\Appdata\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\" & strFailas3
strSPath4 = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%") & "\Appdata\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\" & strFailas4
Set objEmailOptions = objWord.EmailOptions
Set objSignatureObject = objEmailOptions.EmailSignature
Set objSignatureEntries = objSignatureObject.EmailSignatureEntries
If (strCred) Then objSelection.TypeText strName & ", " & strCred Else objSelection.TypeText strName
objSelection.TypeParagraph()

Set adoStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
adoStream.Open
adoStream.Charset = "UTF-8"
adoStream.LoadFromFile "file.txt"
BodyTEXT = adoStream.ReadText(-1)
adoStream.TypeText BodyTEXT
adoStream.Close
Set adoStream = Nothing

Set objSelection = objDoc.Range()
objSignatureEntries.Add "Full Signature", objSelection
objSignatureObject.NewMessageSignature = "Full Signature"
objDoc.Saved = True
objWord.Quit
```

I'm trying to create a VBScript to automatically genarate email signature for all users in Active Directory, but I have a problem. I want to insert UTF8 *.txt file as email signature body but it's not displayed after I run this script. Maybe I need to set it as different variable or something?

Answer (score 0):

VBScript troubleshooting 101: remove `On Error Resume Next`, so you can actually see what goes wrong. Contrary to popular belief the statement doesn't magically make errors disappear. It just prevents the interpreter from telling you about them.

***Never ever*** use globel `On Error Resume Next` in production code.

**steps off soap box**

With that said, you read the text into the variable `BodyTEXT`, which works just fine. However, you then try to call `adoStream.TypeText` with it. Without the global `On Error Resume Next` that statement would have raised an error

> Object doesn't support this property or method.

because `ADODB.Stream` objects don't have such a method.

You probably intended to write `objSelection.TypeText BodyTEXT` instead.